# Updating variables using stringstream

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm new here and very new to writing code.

I'm writing a function using `stringstream` that would take in an `input_string` (`input_string` is read from what I'm assuming is a file that came with my starter code, but its labeled as a ".in" file) and update 3 variables based on the integers that are found in the input string.

When I used my test case, its reading the input string just fine (I ended up putting a `cout << ss.str() << endl;` statement in my function just to make sure it was reading the input from my test case), but its not updating the 3 variables that I would like for it to update - `currentFloor`, `targetFloor`, and `angerLevel`.

I'm not asking for people to do my homework, but more of a better explanation that can help me expand my understanding of `stringstream` and updating variables.

```cpp
Person::Person(string input_string) : Person() {
    string str(input_string);
    stringstream ss(str);
    int x;
    ss >> x;
    string s;
    ss >> s;
    cout << ss.str() << endl; //this cout statement is something I put there to check to see if its reading the input_string with a test case
}
```

My test case

```
0f0t10a3 //what was printed using the cout statement
0 0 Expected 10 3 // suppose to update targetFloor and angerLevel
0 Expected 0 //this works
0 1 Expected 5 6
0 1 Expected 5 6
0 Expected 1
```

Comment: what is `input_string` ?

Comment: I see no variables named `currentFloor`, `targetFloor`, or `angerLevel` in this code.  So why are you expecting them to be updated, if you have no code that tries to update them?  Also, your `str` variable is unnecessary, you can just pass `input_string` as-is to the `stringstream` (in this example, you should be using `istringstream` instead).

Comment: The code you describe has very little in common with the code you posted. Also it would help to know why you think that variables (whatever they are) aren't being updated. It's just as possible that they are being updated but for some reason you are mistaken about that.

Comment: The 3 variables `currentFloor`, `targetFloor`, and `angerLevel` were included into different scope of the code that was provided by my instructors. I assumed that they would be updated, but now after your explanation, I feel foolish in thinking that they would be updated without including them in my `Person::person(string input_string)`...

Also @john I see that they aren't being updated because of my test case where it expects the `targetFloor` to be 10 and `angerLevel` to be 3 in the expected case, but the actual case is still 0, 0 (they were initialized with my default constructor

Answer (score 1):

You can test if the reading from the stream worked:

```
    int x;
    if (ss >> x) {
        std::cout << "Correctly read into X: " << x << "\n";
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Read from ss into X failed.\n"
                  << "Note any subsequent reads will also fail unless"
                  << "you reset the error flag on ss\n";

        ss.clear(); // This will reset all the flags on the stream.

        std::cout << "Check what is on ss that failed\n"
        std::cout << "Bad SS: " << ss.str() << "\n"
   }
```

Comment: When you `clear()` the error state, generally you should also `ignore()` the input that caused `>>` to fail in the first place. Unless you are going to re-try to read the same value using a different data type.

Answer (score 0):

The code below has comments to explain:

```
Person::Person(string input_string) : Person() {
    // create an input stringstream to help you parse input_string
    std::istringstream ss(input_string);

    // some variables to parse values into...
    int x;
    string s;

    if (ss >> x >> s)
        std::cout << "read x=" << x << " and s='" << s << "'\n";
    else
        std::cerr << "unable to parse an int and space-delimited word from '"
            << input_string << "'\n";
}
```

If that doesn't extract the values you expect, the problem will be in the `input_string` value, which you'll see printed in the error message.  If you need help getting the right `input_string` from your input file, then try something like below and search for Q&A on ifstreams to sort yourself out; ask a new question here if stuck...

```
if (std::ifstream in{"some_filename.in"}) {
    std::string input_string;
    while (getline(in, input_string)) {
        Person person{input_string};
        // do something with each person parsed...
    }
}
else
    std::cerr << "unable to open input file\n";
```

Comment: With your example, it was able to only read one int in the `input_string` (test case: 0f0t10a3) while it read f0t10a3 as a string. How can I make it read more integers? I tried to make more int variables to read the other integers into, but I got the "unable to parse an in and delimited word..." when I ran the code and tried to step through to see how this is being done

Comment: If your input string is `0f0t10a3` then you need to think how you want it to be parsed.  After the integer `0`, should it always read one character, then try to read another integer and so on?  If so, add `char c1,c2,c3;` and `int i1,i2,i3,i4;` variables and use `if (ss >> i1 >> c1 >> i2 >> c2 >> i3 >> c3 >> i4)` to parse the lot.  You can add checks for the values in `c1`, `c2` and `c3` to make sure they're sensible characters to encounter.  But, if we don't know what kind of input you're expecting to be parsable, we can only guess at when you'll consider it ok versus an error.

Comment: You can also test that there's nothing unexpected/unwanted remaining in the `istringstream` by appending `>> std::skipws && ss.eof()` to your `if` condition.

Comment: Oh that makes sense. I didn't know that. Ill try that right now!

Comment: OMg! It worked!! Thank you so much! I did not take into account that my variables weren't being updated (simply because I did not have enough dummy variables), so after parsing them, I reassigned `currentFloor`, `targetFloor`, and `angerLevel` to the new variables of f,t,a...Ah thank you so so much!

Comment: @MatthewBlake: you're welcome.  You can off course put `currentFloor`, `targetFloor`, `angerLevel` etc. directly into the `>>` streaming code, and not have `f`, `t` and `a` at all if you like.